# Angular 7 project doesn't publish on Github - shows only ReadMe file (I've used GitHub Pages)

Tags: github, github-pages, git-bash, angular7, angular-cli-ghpages

When I publish Angular projects I usually always do the same thing.. but for some reason it doesn't work.
That's exactly what I wrote: (The repo name is movies)

```
git init

git remote add origin <MyGitHubLink>

git add *

git commit -m 'first-commit'

git push -u origin master

ng build --prod --base-href https://itayperry.github.io/movies (from ghpages on github settings)

ngh --dir dist/movies
```

Then I get the message *** Successfully published! but all I see is the README file.

Please help me!!

The repository: https://github.com/itayperry/movies

The published page: https://itayperry.github.io/movies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to go to the settings page and change to GitHub-Pages branch.
Problem solved :)